# Limitation in output generated by a class

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, if-statement

Let's say that I want to create a class **circle** that, provided a value **r** and a value **delta_r**, can calculate the annulus area of a couple of circles.
Afterwards, using this class, I want to create a list with several couples of circles.

How can I add a condition, built in the class, that allows to append values **only if r < 7**? So that, in the example, the list C is still created but includes only results till r=6.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import pi

class circle:
    def __init__(self, r=1, delta_r=0.1):
        self.r = r
        self.delta_r = delta_r

        self.area1 = pi*r**2
        self.area2 = pi*(r+delta_r)**2
        self.annulus = self.area2 - self.area1

C_range = np.arange(1, 10)
C = []
for n in C_range:
    C.append(circle(n, 0.2))
```

Comment: Maybe give `circle` a `max_r` attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below you can find 2 ways to protect circle from wrong r.
The first one is external protection - the code that creates the circle make sure it uses valid r values.
The second one (and the recommended one) is to let circle protect itself.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import pi

class Circle:
    def __init__(self, r=1, delta_r=0.1):
        self.r = r
        self.delta_r = delta_r

        self.area1 = pi*r**2
        self.area2 = pi*(r+delta_r)**2
        self.annulus = self.area2 - self.area1

C_range = np.arange(1, 10)
circle_list = [Circle(r, 0.2) for r in np.arange(1, 10) if r < 7]
print(circle_list)

class CirclePlus:
    def __init__(self, r=1, delta_r=0.1):
        if r >= 7:
          raise ValueError(f"Invalid r value {r}")
        else:
          self.r = r
          self.delta_r = delta_r

          self.area1 = pi*r**2
          self.area2 = pi*(r+delta_r)**2
          self.annulus = self.area2 - self.area1
```